# /how to read xml tags and its data using php?

Tags: php, xml

How to get the data inside of tag `'goldenKingCobra'`

```
<livestock>
<goldenKingCobra name="Indus" age="4" sex="f" /> 
<goldenKingCobra name="Nile" age="8" sex="f" /> 
<goldenKingCobra name="Tigris" age="9.5" sex="f" />     
</livestock>
```

I need values in an array format

> array(0=>array("name"=>"Indus","age"=>"4","sex"=>"f"), 1=>array("name"=>"Nile","age"=>"8","sex"=>"f"),
>   2=>array("name"=>"Tigris","age"=>"9.5","sex"=>"f"));

please help me

Answer (score 0):

With `xml_parse_into_struct()`. See: http://php.net/manual/es/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

```
<?php
$xml = "<livestock>
<goldenKingCobra name="Indus" age="4" sex="f" /> 
<goldenKingCobra name="Nile" age="8" sex="f" /> 
<goldenKingCobra name="Tigris" age="9.5" sex="f" />     
</livestock>";
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);

// array of indexes
print_r($index);

// array of values
print_r($vals);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$data = '<livestock>
         <goldenKingCobra name="Indus" age="4" sex="f" /> 
         <goldenKingCobra name="Nile" age="8" sex="f" /> 
         <goldenKingCobra name="Tigris" age="9.5" sex="f" />     
         </livestock>';

$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

foreach($xmlData as $x){
  echo $x['name'].'<br>';
  echo $x['age'].'<br>';
  echo $x['sex'].'<br>';
}
```